# Where and how can I override markup for Quicktabs accordion displays?

Tags: 7, theming

We've run in to an issue where we need to override/revise the output that is created by the [Quick Tabs module](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) in order to make the display compliant with the [standard from W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#accordion).

I'm sure we're not the only one to have ever run in to this issue, but I cannot find anything from anyone on how they approached handling this with their projects.

We've looked at jquery, we've looked at the structure inside the Quick Tabs module as modules are known to have template files that can then be overridden in the theme. However, I cannot find anywhere to modify/alter the markup for what we need to do in order to make our display, which is one accordion instance with 10-12 blocks associated.

Can you help me find where I can override the HTML display markup that's output from our block and quicktabs so that we can rearrange/modify the structure so that it's compliant with the standard?

Comment: Have you seen these hooks? https://cgit.drupalcode.org/quicktabs/tree/quicktabs.api.php?h=7.x-3.x

Comment: This, plus all themes defined at https://cgit.drupalcode.org/quicktabs/tree/quicktabs.module?h=7.x-3.x#n104, have tried preprocessing them already via `MYTHEME_preprocess_qt_quicktabs($variables)` and `MYTHEME_preprocess_qt_accordion($variables)` etc.?